# como crear un while para validar que se ingrese datos en un intervalo de 1 hasta 5?

Tags: c++

```
int datos[4];
cout<<"Tipo de turismo"<<endl;

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    cout<<"["<<i+1<<"] -"<<turismo[i]<<endl;
}

cout<<"Ingrese la opcion"<<endl;
cin>>datos[0];
    
while(datos[0]< 0 && datos[0]>6){
    cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese la opcion"<<endl;
    cin>>datos[0];
}

cout<<"El turismo escogido fue :"<<turismo[datos[0]-1]<<endl;
```

el problema viene que son varios arreglos que almacenan caracteres entonces cada opcion la estoy almacenando en un arreglo que llame **int datos[3];** para almacenar cada opciones escogida, esto es solo un pequeño trozo de mi código **A COMO MODO DE EJEMPLO** entonces queria saber si podrian ayudarme a decirme como podria crear un while para validar que la opcion que se ingrese al arreglo sea entre 1 y 5 que es el total de caracteres que tiene el arreglo?
igual puedo usar acepciones pero no estoy segura como usarlas bien
**no puedo modificar mi codigo, debo seguir trabajando con este arreglo int datos[4] que cree para mi proyecto**
basicamente lo que busco lograr es esto

ingrese una opcion : **19**

error ingrese una opcion entre 1 y 5

ingrese una opcion :

Comment: Por más que leo la pregunta no entiendo nada, ¿Podrías reformular la pregunta, por favor?

Comment: No sería mejor emplear una estructura `do-while`?? Por otro lado, la comparación que tienes en el `while` no creo que sea correcta ya que nunca se va a cumplir la norma que marcas, para que se cumpla la lógica que estás implementando deberás poner una `OR`: `while( (datos[0]<0) || (datos[0]>6) )`. No obstante, estoy de acuerdo con @eferion en que no se entiende bien la pregunta.

Comment: ya les puse un ejemplo jejeje de lo que busco hacer lo unico que quier es que cuando se digite en el cout<<"Ingrese una opcion" si la opcion es mayor a 5 o menor a 0 que tire un error, pero como lo que esta agarrando mis opciones digitadas es un arreglo y no una simple variable el while me tira error

Comment: igual ya me ayudaste @Londo jejeje era que no avia metido bien cada proposicion dentro de parentesis jejejje, muchas gracias te daria el boto pero realmente nose como dartelo porque solo comentaste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para validar que se ingrese un valor positivo en un intervalo entre dos números, empecemos por almacenar datos en un valor sin signo, así será imposible obtener valores negativos:

```
   unsigned int datos[4];
// ~~~~~~~~ <--- Sin signo, no puede almacenar valores negativos.
```

Ahora, en el bucle debemos comprobar que el valor esté entre el intervalo X e Y:

```
do
{
    std::cout << "Ingrese la opcion\n";
    std::cin >> datos[0];
} while ((datos[0] > 0) && (datos[0] < 6));
//                   ^            ^ <--- Límite superior, inferior que seis
//                    \
//                     \__ Límite inferior, mayor que cero
```